# Create vue mixin for theme switcher vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have created three themes, light, default and dark. I'm now trying to create a toggle in the footer so I can switch between each theme.

With the advice of @jogarcia I have changed my code to the following.

The mixin is now in its own file called `themes.js`

```
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      currentTheme: "",
    };
  },
  mounted() {
    const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme-colour");
    if (!storedTheme) {
      this.currentTheme = "theme-default";
    } else {
      this.currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme-colour");
    }
  },
  methods: {
    toggleTheme() {
      const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme-colour");
      if (!storedTheme) {
        localStorage.setItem("theme-colour", "theme-light");
        this.currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme-colour");
      }
      if (storedTheme === "theme-default") {
        localStorage.setItem("theme-colour", "theme-light");
        this.currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme-colour");
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("theme-colour", "theme-dark");
        this.currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme-colour");
      }
    },
  },
};
```

Therefore I have imported the file in both the `app.vue` and Footer component by doing `import themes from "@/mixins/themes";` and `mixins: [themes]` in the export respectively.

I have also added `:class="currentTheme"` to the `app.vue` file.

However, I'm still running into a few more issues.

1. How do I get the theme class to change dynamically?

Here is a gif of what I mean, as you can see I can toggle, the value is being changed in localStorage but the class name isn't changing in the main app div.

https://i.gyazo.com/2044ff9293328aaaae8810272ffc6a5a.mp4

Update:

I've updated the bind in `app.vue` to `:class="[currentTheme]"` but this still doesn't work.

Here is a new GIF https://i.gyazo.com/2f1d6a98b51e2d00c8ba748940016f55.mp4

As you can see the default theme loads by default which is now correct, however, when I toggle to dark the data `currentTheme` doesn't change. It only changes on refresh because of localstorage and I can't select the theme in the dropdown using Vue devtools if that's any issue as well.

`App.vue`

```
<template>
  <div
    id="app"
    class="flex flex-col min-h-screen h-full font-sans text-copy-primary leading-normal tracking-wide overflow-x-hidden"
    :class="[currentTheme]"
  >
    <Navigation />
    <DealBanner discountValue="20" date="April 26, 2020 12:00" discountCode="RELEASE" />
    <router-view class="flex-1" />
    <Footer />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import themes from "@/mixins/themes";
import Navigation from "@/components/Navigation";
import DealBanner from "@/components/DealBanner";
import Footer from "@/components/Footer";

export default {
  name: "App",
  components: {
    Navigation,
    DealBanner,
    Footer
  },
  mixins: [themes]
};
</script>
```

`Footer.vue` (shorted)

```
<template>
  <footer
    class="px-6 xl:px-0 py-6 bg-theme-primary text-copy-primary border-t border-theme-ternary"
  >
    <div class="flex flex-col justify-between lg:flex-row lg:items-center xl:px-
      <div class="text-center">
        <p>Theme Switcher</p>
        <div @click="toggleTheme">Toggle</div>
        {{currentTheme}}
      </div>
    </div>
  </footer>
</template>

<script>
import themes from "@/mixins/themes";
export default {
  name: "Footer",
  mixins: [themes]
};
</script>
...
```

Comment: What issue are you having here?

Comment: I get `error    'toggleThemeMixin' is not defined`

Comment: ok, then put the mixin code in footer component only, or if you want it to have access in all components then create a global mixin.

Comment: I want the switcher to be in the footer but I need it to change the class in the main app div so that's why I thought a mixin would be the best choice and share it between components, so it needs to be shared between components.

Comment: I've created a global mixin but the toggle isn't working in the footer. I'll update the question @palaѕн

Comment: Are you using vue.js as a library or vue-cli?

Comment: vue-cli @jogarcia

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems in your mixin.

#### Local Storage.

Be sure that you are saving **theme-color** else you will get an error if is not in the local storage.

```
methods: {
    toggleTheme() {
      const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme-colour");
      if (!storedTheme) {
        localStorage.setItem("theme-colour", "theme-light");
        this.currentTheme = "theme-dark";
      }
      if (storedTheme === "theme-light") {
        localStorage.setItem("theme-colour", "theme-light");
        this.currentTheme = "theme-dark";
      } else {
        localStorage.setItem("theme-colour", "theme-dark");
        this.currentTheme = "theme-light";
      }
    },
  },
```

#### Structure of the mixin

Am not sure if you are importing the mixin correctly or not so am going to add this here just in case. This is the way i make and import mixin, following the docs of course. If you are using the vue cli, the mixin should be on its own file, this way follows that idea.

mixin.js

```
export default {
  data() {},
  methods {}
}
```

AnyVueComponent.vue

```
<template>
...
</template>
<script>
  import mixin from 'path to my mixin';
  export default {
    ......
    mixins: [mixin]
    ......
  }
</script>
```

#### currentTheme variable reactivity

You don't have to keep loading from the localStorage you can save all the times but load just on mounted, kind of like this:

mixin.js

```
export default {
  data() {
    currentTheme: ''
  },
  mounted(){
    const storedTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme-colour");
    if (!storedTheme) {
      this.currentTheme = "theme-light"
    }else{
      this.currentTheme = localStorage.getItem("theme-colour");
    }
  },
  methods {...}
}
```

Using this way for class binding.

```
//Any format you want to do to currentTheme do it inside the computed
:class=[currentTheme]
```

Check this sandbox:

https://codesandbox.io/s/exciting-keller-nowok?file=/src/App.vue

Comment: Thanks for the explanations, I've changed my code around a bit and I can see the toggling when I click the `toggle` button, localStorage is changing but I can't seem to set a default theme and the class doesn't change dynamically. I'll update the question.

Comment: Updated the question

Comment: @debugabug you just have to load one time , and save many, i changed my answer check it

Comment: I've swapped out the current code, for the new code but it's not switching dynamically. Here's a gif https://i.gyazo.com/81c65a5391c89512893260cba0da0606.mp4

Comment: @debugabug i made a little change at the end, that should work, if not update your post with the new errors

Comment: Updated the question, with a new GIF and some context

Comment: I did change it yes, I was using that change in the GIF

Comment: @debugabug add the template part

Comment: Added App.vue and footer

Comment: @debugabug let's ,move this to a chat so i can help you better

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211969/discussion-between-jogarcia-and-debugabug).